# 0-copy inter-process communication on Unix without using the filesystem

Tags: unix, filesystems, ipc, mmap, unix-socket

If I have to move a moderate amount of memory between two processes, I can do the following:

- create a file for writing
- ftruncate to desired size
- mmap and unlink it
- use as desired

When another process requires that data, it:

- connects to the first process through a unix socket
- the first process sends the fd of the file through a unix socket message
- mmap the fd
- use as desired

This allows us to move memory between processes without any copy - but the file created must be on a memory-mounted filesystem, otherwise we might get a disk hit, which would degrade performance. Is there a way to do something like that without using a filesystem? A malloc-like function that returned a fd along with a pointer would do it.

[**Edit**] Having a file descriptor provides also a reference count mechanism that is maintained by the kernel.

Comment: [Shared memory](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html)?

Comment: Isn't System V shared memory considered obsolete?

Comment: Rarely used? Most probably. Obsolete? I don't think so, and I don't know any evidence of that.

Comment: @Penz: System V shared memory is more SUS (Single Unix Specification) than POSIX, but is listed at the [POSIX 2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) site without any 'obs' marker.

Answer (score 4):

Is there anything wrong with [System V](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmat.html) or [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html) shared memory (which are somewhat different, but end up with the same result)?  With any such system, you have to worry about coordination between the processes as they access the memory, but that is true with memory-mapped files too.

Comment: shm_open would be exactly what I was looking for if there was a way to create an anonymous shared memory object and just use the fd.

System V also has this issue, and others: the persistency requires explicit deallocation, which can be a problem when the same data is sent to more than one problem. With a fd, we have the reference count for free.